# query to range of the IP using a linq

Tags: c#, linq

The IP is stored in the database as a range and I want to query it

data

| IP | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 123.123.123.0/16 | A |
| 123.124.0.0/20 | B |
| 123.255.1.0/100 | C |
| 123.255.1.101/255 | D |

query

```
IpCheck = "123.124.11.25"

string country = data.Where(i => i.IP == IpCheck)
              .Select(c => c.Country)
              .FirstOrDefault();

//Result Country:B
```

Comment: Those aren't IP addresses, they're IPv4 addresses with a subnet mask. That's not the same thing.

Comment: What is the exact type of your `IP` column? If you're using a string/textual type then you won't be able to perform proper range-searches of your data. I don't think using an RDBMS is the best way to store or represent this information because with CIDR you can't segment IP address blocks on octet boundaries, it's per-bit. Hmm, this is actually a complicated problem...

Answer (score 0):

For fetching a data in range you have to split your IP to check in to the database.  In your case you want the data which has second point is 124. So you can simply split your string with **"."**

```
string IpCheck = "123.124.11.25"  

IPCheck= IpCheck.Substring(0,IpCheck.IndexOf('.', IpCheck.IndexOf('.') + 1)); // this will return 123.124 

string country = data.Where(i =>i.IP.Substring(0,i.IP.IndexOf('.', i.IP.IndexOf('.') + 1))==IpCheck)
          .Select(c => c.Country)
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now above query will return all the range value starting from **123.124**